# menu get object doesn't seem to work

Tags: 7, theming

I'm a trying to pass a var, in this case the var "$node" to the page.tpl.php.
Tried everything for three days but i cannot make it work despite my code is correct apparently. Tried different ways but when i tried to check with isset if the var exists, it returns false. I really need it, so i can check pages and nodes.

This is my code:

template.tpl.php

```
  function agn_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
      $vars['node'] = $node->type;
  }
  }
```

page.tpl.php

```
<?php if (isset($node)){
   print "true";
}else{
   print "false";
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting ... but what is your actual question?

Comment: Why overwrite node with the node type?

Comment: The question IS that i cannot make the node variable to work. It keeps retutning false when i Check if exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$node is already available in page.tpl.php on node pages without you having to do anything. See the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21page.tpl.php/7.x)

Comment: Thanks but it keeps me showing false when i Check with isset. And It gives me node IS not defined.

Comment: Are you actually on a node page?

Comment: Gave me true... I was am idiot that i didnt try that...